# How to access to a IIS website externally?

Tags: asp.net, iis, portforwarding, wan

I've created a web in asp net core and it is published in IIS and works well accesing in my local network, but now I need to access in another pc out of my network.

**My ip info is this:**

Public IP ......................: 190.62.96.84

IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.5

subred . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0

Gateway. . . . . : 192.168.1.1

**I've set the site like this:**

[image]

**I've created a rule in my firewall with the port 8080**

[image]

**And finally I set Add a port forwarding like this:**

[image]

I've also used the port 80 instead 8080 but no success... What I am doing wrong? 
There other way to access to my website externally?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your host is blank. Are you only accessing this site via IP address, or are you trying to access this site via a domain name (DNS)?

Comment: Only via IP Address

Comment: @HBlackorby What's wrong with blank host? Blank host site binding accepts more HTTP requests, as it won't check Host header.

Comment: Some ISP's block specific ports. You might try a random high port to externally expose your site through and see if that gives you better luck.

Comment: @LexLi, nothing is wrong with it. It allows you to access your site via IP address without a domain, which many people don't want to allow, especially if you are re-using external IP addresses. It's fine if that's what you want to do. It's what he wants to do in this case. I was just making sure he wasn't trying to access it via a specific domain over a shared IP address.